# Is there a way to read a text file into a Memory<char> or Span<char> line by line instead of strings?

Tags: c#, .net, file-handling

I'm looking for ways to optimize my COBOL preprocessor, we're reading each source file using `File.ReadLines()` and while this does work currently, it is also not very efficient because of all the string allocations and string manipulations during the preprocessing phase.

We have to remove the first 0-7 characters of a line depending on the free/fixed directives, clear or insert certain lines depending on some directives, and also remove the directives after preprocessing them, and doing all this with a list of strings turns out to be quite expensive.

Since Spans are supposed to be more efficient, is there a way of reading the source text line by line into a `Span<char>` or `Memory<char>`?

So far we've tried `File.ReadLines()` and `File.ReadAllLines()` but those are too memory inefficient when there's a lot of source lines, and we can't find a method that returns a `Span<char>` or `Memory<char>` from a text file.

Comment: `Span<char>` may be efficient when you already have the string as a string, and expose a part of it as another "string". You cannot do that if you haven't read from the file into an actual string.

Comment: @GSerg would it make sense to read line by line with `File.ReadLines()` and then copying them as a Span into a Memory<char>?

Comment: That depends on why you want to do that. If you want to instruct another method to operate on a substring of a line you just read, then sure, expose the substring as a span (as opposed to "copying" it as a span which would have defeated the purpose).

Comment: I'd be suspicious of your assumption that the actual problem is in putting the data into strings.  Doing that for even very large files tends to not be a problem.  There are lots of really bad ways of using those strings though, especially given that you're trying to modify each line a bit. There are lots of ways of doing that *really* inefficiently (and also ways of doing that efficiently).  You're most likely creating lots of intermediate strings that are killing your performance, rather than killing performance by reading the file itself into strings.

Comment: @Servy I'm currently doing it by substring and replace, would that be the issue? What should I use instead?

Comment: @KTSnowy Without knowing what you need to do, or how you're trying to do it, no one can tell you for sure what you're doing wrong or how you should be doing it instead.  It's just unlikely that what you're asking for in the question is unlikely to help.

Comment: This is indeed a practical concern I know of, one that occupied the Roslyn team as well.  You'll want to take a look at their code, https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn

Answer (score 1):

Spans are nothing but a generic-ish, light-weight way to read/write a bunch of values, but those values have to exist in memory somewhere for you to initialize a span over them in the first place. In other words, spans aren't a replacement for reading lines from a file.

Now, the backing for spans doesn't have to be strings, and if you're parsing very large files you probably shouldn't be using streams in the first place, that's the reason by `MemoryMappedFile` exists. And creating a view accessor over it gives you a span to work with that's backed by the OS virtual memory manager. Write your own parsing on it and it's as efficient as working with pointers in something like C++. Which should be trivial, any high schooler can probably increment a pointer until it gets to a space, then do something with the value parsed.

> string manipulations

Given your misunderstanding of something as basic as a span, I'd be very worried about that if I were you. String manipulations can *very easily* kill your application if you do them wrong. And given that you don't paste any code, you probably don't even know that there's good ways and bad ways of doing it, ranging from literal `string` manipulations (reallocating and copying data over and over) to `StringBuilder` to zero-allocation manipulation over `stackalloc` bytes (like `ValueStringBuilder` does in the C# compiler).

Comment: From what I can see on the C# docs, a `MemoryMappedFile` allows me to get a view of the file when I already know what offset and size I'm looking for. So I would have to read the file anyways to figure out what the offset and sizes are for the COBOL source code. The issue is not very large files, it's that I HAVE to preprocess the file before actually parsing the code in it.

Comment: You thought you could avoid reading the file to get to the data inside? I don't understand what the point you're trying to make is. "I HAVE to preprocess the file" -- no you don't, you just seem to want to for some reason.

Comment: "no you don't, you just seem to want to for some reason." So how do I preprocess the source code without preprocessing the source code?

Comment: Sure I did, you mentioned substring and what I assume are string copies with one character different (what you call "replace"). You don't need to preprocess anything, you just need to process your file. The way you do it is up to you, and you chose to create dozens of temporary strings to allocate, copy between them, deallocate and move the entire generation of GC around to fill in your holes.

Comment: @Blindy I don't believe native numbers are parsed (at least it was not the case before Net5 like `Int32.Parse("١", NumberStyles.Any, new CultureInfo("ar-sa"))` ). I'm not sure which one you referring to.

Comment: @Blindy since you seem to be focusing on the "finding a space" thing, I just want to point out that that is not what I'm trying to do. I'm writing a COBOL preprocessor, which requires preprocessing the source code according to the rules of each preprocessor directive. That's not something "any high schooler" can do, it is not trivial to write a COBOL preprocessor.